# Access database access errors second time around? c#

Tags: c#, database, list, ms-access

Hey guys I am using C# and I've successfully accessed my database and assigned variables etc but I want to access it a second time and for some reason it's failing at this point:

```
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Here is the code snippets that might help you guys understand better.  If anyone can point out what I might be doing wrong I'd be deeply grateful.

```
        //#########################
        //   DATABASE OPERATIONS
        //#########################

        // Create the database connections
        string usersConnString = (@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\kronix\Documents\theitguy.accdb");

        OleDbConnection theitguyDBConn = new OleDbConnection(usersConnString);

        //==============================
        //   Populate Customers Table
        //==============================

        try
        {
            // Open theitguy database connection
            theitguyDBConn.Open();

            // Select the fields you want to retrieve from in the database
            string selectString = "SELECT ID, Name, Surname, Address, Town, County, Postcode, HomeNumber, MobileNumber, Email FROM Customers";

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(selectString, theitguyDBConn);

            //Send the CommandText to the connection, and then build an OleDbDataReader.
            //Note: The OleDbDataReader is forward-only.
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            // PROCESS THE DATABASE AND ADD THEM TO THE LISTS FOR USE LATER IN THE PROGRAM
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                custID.Add(reader["ID"].ToString());
                custName.Add(reader["Name"].ToString());
                custSurname.Add(reader["Surname"].ToString());
                custAddress.Add(reader["Address"].ToString());
                custTown.Add(reader["Town"].ToString());
                custCounty.Add(reader["County"].ToString());
                custPostcode.Add(reader["Postcode"].ToString());
                custHomeNumber.Add(reader["HomeNumber"].ToString());
                custMobileNumber.Add(reader["MobileNumber"].ToString());
                custEmail.Add(reader["Email"].ToString());
            }

            // Dispose of the data once used
            reader.Dispose();
            reader.Close();

            // Close the database connection
            theitguyDBConn.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write("ERROR 201 (Form2): Error reading Customers table in theitguy Database\n");
        }



        //==============================
        //   Populate Repairs Table
        //==============================

        try
        {
            // Open theitguy database connection
            theitguyDBConn.Open();

            // Select the fields you want to retrieve from in the database
            string selectString = "SELECT ID, CustID, Name, Surname, DateIn, Device, Colour, ContactNumber1, ContactNumber2, EstimatedCost, ReportedProblem, Diagnostics, EngineerRemarks, WorkCompleted, PartsUsed, PartsCost, PartsID, Engineer, TotalCost, DateCompleted FROM Repairs";

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(selectString, theitguyDBConn);

            //Send the CommandText to the connection, and then build an OleDbDataReader.
            //Note: The OleDbDataReader is forward-only.
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();   //###IT'S FAILING HERE!!!###


            // PROCESS THE DATABASE AND ADD THEM TO THE LISTS FOR USE LATER IN THE PROGRAM
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                repID.Add(reader["ID"].ToString());
                repCustID.Add(reader["ID"].ToString());
                repName.Add(reader["ID"].ToString());
                repSurname.Add(reader["ID"].ToString());
                repDateIn.Add(reader["ID"].ToString());
                repDevice.Add(reader["ID"].ToString());
                repColour.Add(reader["ID"].ToString());
                repContactNumber1.Add(reader["ID"].ToString());
                repContactNumber2.Add(reader["ID"].ToString());
                repEstimatedCost.Add(reader["ID"].ToString());
                repReportedProblem.Add(reader["ID"].ToString());
                repDiagnostics.Add(reader["ID"].ToString());
                repEngineerRemarks.Add(reader["ID"].ToString());
                repWorkCompleted.Add(reader["ID"].ToString());
                repPartsUsed.Add(reader["ID"].ToString());
                repPartsCost.Add(reader["ID"].ToString());
                repPartsID.Add(reader["ID"].ToString());
                repEngineer.Add(reader["ID"].ToString());
                repTotalCost.Add(reader["ID"].ToString());
                repDateCompleted.Add(reader["ID"].ToString());
            }

            // Dispose of the data once used
            reader.Dispose();
            reader.Close();

            // Close the database connection
            theitguyDBConn.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write("ERROR 202 (Form2): Error reading Repairs table in theitguy Database\n");
        }
```

Comment: what is the error and which of the code block is throwing the error?

Comment: When you catch the exception, instead of printing some text, why don't you print the error message. Or better yet, ex.ToString(). That will tell you exactly what and where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Whoopsie, I made a boo boo .... I found out my problem.

I forgot to name the following properly:

```
            repCustID.Add(reader["ID"].ToString());
            repName.Add(reader["ID"].ToString());
            repSurname.Add(reader["ID"].ToString());
```

Should be

```
            repCustID.Add(reader["CustID"].ToString());
            repName.Add(reader["Name"].ToString());
            repSurname.Add(reader["Surname"].ToString());
```

Silly me.

Answer (score 0):

Actually that wasn't the only fault...... the REAL PROBLEM was that I was trying to convert currency type in access into a string.

Comment: You can edit your original question rather than post an "answer" like this.